# element currently not visible so may not be interacted with

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am trying to locate the input box. below is the C# code i am using for locating the field.

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='potential-val-field']")).Click();
```

Below is HTML code for the input box

```
<div class="controls">

<input id="potential-val-field" class="m-wrap span12" type="text" value="" tabindex="7" placeholder="0" name="PotentialValue" maxlength="30" data-val-regex-pattern="([-,0-9]+)" data-val-regex="Amount must be a whole number with no decimal places." data-val-length-max="19" data-val-length="Value cannot exceed 15 digits" data-val="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></input>

</div>
```

Sometime it works but maximum time it is throwing an exception of element not visible and 
 so may not be interacted with.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you dynamically sets visibility via javascript/ajax and your test executes very fast, you need to use Wait construction